# How to convert Arrays of objects of objects into one dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have an example of javascript array of object within an object there is object. So I basically want only that into one dimensional array.

I have searched lots of Q's on SO but none of them as per my requirement.

What I have

```
[
{
"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7",
"value": {
  "city": "Mahbubnagar",
  "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
  "country": "India"
}
},
{
"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c8",
"value": {
  "city": "Udgir",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "country": "India"
}
},
{
"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c9",
"value": {
  "city": "Umarga",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "country": "India"
}
},
{
"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68ca",
"value": {
  "city": "Umarkhed",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "country": "India"
}
},
{
"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68cb",
"value": {
  "city": "Umred",
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "country": "India"
}
}
]
```

And I simply want this array of objects into an array

```
[
  "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7",
  "Mahbubnagar",
  "Andhra Pradesh",
  "India",
],[
  "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c9",
  "Umarga",
  "Maharashtra",
  "India",
],[
  "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68ca",
  "Umarkhed",
  "Maharashtra",
  "India",
],[
  "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7",
  "Mahbubnagar",
  "Andhra Pradesh",
  "India",
],
```

The array of objects could be have more children in other words you can say its dynamic content.

What I have used so far is

```
var object= property.value.elements;
        var finalArray = object.map(function (obj) {
          return obj.id;
        });
        console.log(finalArray);
```

Which is giving me only list of Id's

It's not duplicate question please verify before marking it as Duplicate.

Comment: Your example output is not syntactically correct.

Comment: How its not correct ? @ninesalt

Comment: I have added what I have tried @NinaScholz

Comment: Copy/paste your output again...what you've posted is incorrect

Comment: Your output is just a series of arrays not wrapped in an array. You probably mean to wrap the strings in an object `[{}, {}...]`

Comment: Can you give some examples of how the input might differ? Will it just be more properties in `value` for instance, or something else?

Comment: That's not my output actually its more or less like that. I only want array of objects to only one dimensional array. Ignore syntax error @Dzhambazov

Comment: yeah its wrapped inside of array like `data:[thatismyarray]` @ninesalt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arr = [{"id":"59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7","value":{"city":"Mahbubnagar","state":"Andhra Pradesh","country":"India"}},{"id":"59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c8","value":{"city":"Udgir","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}},{"id":"59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c9","value":{"city":"Umarga","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}},{"id":"59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68ca","value":{"city":"Umarkhed","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}},{"id":"59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68cb","value":{"city":"Umred","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}}];

function getVals(obj, arr) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(typeof value === "object") {
      arr = [...arr, ...getVals(obj[key], arr)];
    } else {
      arr.push(value);
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

var resp = arr.map((item) => {
  let temp = [];
  getVals(item, temp);
  return temp;
});
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: Does this work on many levels of objects inside array or just two level @nikhil

Comment: Thanks a lot @nikhil

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a value of the object is an object an take the flattened valued for the result.

```js
function flat(object) {
    return Object
        .values(object)
        .reduce((r, v) => r.concat(v && typeof v === 'object' ? flat(v) : v), []);
}

var array = [{ id: "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7", value: { city: "Mahbubnagar", state: "Andhra Pradesh", country: "India" } }, { id: "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c8", value: { city: "Udgir", state: "Maharashtra", country: "India" } }, { id: "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c9", value: { city: "Umarga", state: "Maharashtra", country: "India" } }, { id: "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68ca", value: { city: "Umarkhed", state: "Maharashtra", country: "India" } }, { id: "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68cb", value: { city: "Umred", state: "Maharashtra", country: "India" } }],
    result = array.map(flat);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isnt the easiest way to do it. Just loop over all the objects and extract their values.

```
let x = [{"id": "59cf758f7bdf8d2e0c1c68c7", "value": {...}, ..] 
let res = []

x.forEach((obj, index) => {
  res.push([obj.id, obj.value.city, obj.value.state, obj.value.country])
}) 

console.log(res)
```